# PrepareForSegue works, but accessing destination's variables crashes application

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying to set the text component of a label in the method prepareForSegue but the application is crashing when the method is executed, i've looked at other discussions but none of them have helped me, I am programming in swift in the latest version of xCode and building to an iPhone.
When I remove the line that sets the label's text to "Meal name", no crash occurs.
The breakpoint is on the line that sets the label's text.
If anyone can help me that would be great, thank you.

-- Edit --

`prepareForSegue` code of FirstViewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let dest : SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
    dest.mealNameLabel.text = "Meal Name"
}
```

Full stack trace: (-> is break)

```
    libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ():
    0x1001de55c <+0>:   stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
    0x1001de560 <+4>:   mov    x29, sp
    0x1001de564 <+8>:   sub    sp, sp, #16               ; =16 
    0x1001de568 <+12>:  and    w8, w2, #0x1
    0x1001de56c <+16>:  tbnz   w8, #0, 0x1001de58c       ; <+48>
    0x1001de570 <+20>:  tbnz   x1, #63, 0x1001de5c8      ; <+108>
    0x1001de574 <+24>:  add    x1, x0, x1
    0x1001de578 <+28>:  mov    x2, x3
    0x1001de57c <+32>:  mov    x3, x4
    0x1001de580 <+36>:  mov    x4, x5
    0x1001de584 <+40>:  bl     0x1002265b0               ; function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded> of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)

->  0x1001de588 <+44>:  brk    #0x1
    0x1001de58c <+48>:  str    xzr, [sp, #8]
    0x1001de590 <+52>:  cmp    x0, w0, uxtw
    0x1001de594 <+56>:  b.ne   0x1001de6e0               ; <+388>
    0x1001de598 <+60>:  lsr    w8, w0, #11
    0x1001de59c <+64>:  cmp    w8, #26                   ; =26 
    0x1001de5a0 <+68>:  b.hi   0x1001de5ec               ; <+144>
    0x1001de5a4 <+72>:  cmp    w0, #128                  ; =128 
    0x1001de5a8 <+76>:  b.lo   0x1001de630               ; <+212>
    0x1001de5ac <+80>:  cmp    w0, #2048                 ; =2048 
    0x1001de5b0 <+84>:  b.hs   0x1001de660               ; <+260>
    0x1001de5b4 <+88>:  movz   x8, #0
    0x1001de5b8 <+92>:  movz   x10, #0
    0x1001de5bc <+96>:  lsr    w9, w0, #6
    0x1001de5c0 <+100>: orr    w9, w9, #0xffffffc0
    0x1001de5c4 <+104>: b      0x1001de694               ; <+312>
    0x1001de5c8 <+108>: adr    x0, #723338               ; "fatal error"
    0x1001de5cc <+112>: nop    
    0x1001de5d0 <+116>: adr    x3, #723840               ; "UnsafeBufferPointer with negative count"
    0x1001de5d4 <+120>: nop    
    0x1001de5d8 <+124>: movz   w1, #0xb
    0x1001de5dc <+128>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
    0x1001de5e0 <+132>: movz   w4, #0x27
    0x1001de5e4 <+136>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
    0x1001de5e8 <+140>: bl     0x1001de55c               ; <+0>
    0x1001de5ec <+144>: cmp    w0, #14, lsl #12          ; =57344 
    0x1001de5f0 <+148>: b.lo   0x1001de63c               ; <+224>
    0x1001de5f4 <+152>: cmp    w0, #272, lsl #12         ; =1114112 
    0x1001de5f8 <+156>: b.hs   0x1001de738               ; <+476>
    0x1001de5fc <+160>: lsr    w8, w0, #6
    0x1001de600 <+164>: lsr    w9, w0, #16
    0x1001de604 <+168>: cbz    w9, 0x1001de664           ; <+264>
    0x1001de608 <+172>: lsr    w9, w0, #18
    0x1001de60c <+176>: orr    w9, w9, #0xf0
    0x1001de610 <+180>: cmp    w9, w9, uxtb
    0x1001de614 <+184>: b.ne   0x1001de6e0               ; <+388>
    0x1001de618 <+188>: orr    w10, wzr, #0xffffff80
    0x1001de61c <+192>: bfxil  w10, w0, #12, #6
    0x1001de620 <+196>: and    x12, x9, #0xff
    0x1001de624 <+200>: str    x12, [sp, #8]
    0x1001de628 <+204>: orr    w11, wzr, #0x1
    0x1001de62c <+208>: b      0x1001de674               ; <+280>
    0x1001de630 <+212>: movz   x8, #0
    0x1001de634 <+216>: movz   x9, #0
    0x1001de638 <+220>: b      0x1001de6d0               ; <+372>
    0x1001de63c <+224>: adr    x0, #723222               ; "fatal error"
    0x1001de640 <+228>: nop    
    0x1001de644 <+232>: adr    x3, #726652               ; "high- and low-surrogate code points are not valid Unicode scalar values"
    0x1001de648 <+236>: nop    
    0x1001de64c <+240>: movz   w1, #0xb
    0x1001de650 <+244>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
    0x1001de654 <+248>: movz   w4, #0x47
    0x1001de658 <+252>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
    0x1001de65c <+256>: bl     0x1001de55c               ; <+0>
    0x1001de660 <+260>: lsr    w8, w0, #6
    0x1001de664 <+264>: lsr    w9, w0, #12
    0x1001de668 <+268>: movz   x11, #0
    0x1001de66c <+272>: movz   x12, #0
    0x1001de670 <+276>: orr    w10, w9, #0xffffffe0
    0x1001de674 <+280>: lsl    x13, x11, #3
    0x1001de678 <+284>: orr    w9, wzr, #0xffffff80
    0x1001de67c <+288>: bfxil  w9, w8, #0, #6
    0x1001de680 <+292>: and    w8, w10, #0xff
    0x1001de684 <+296>: lsl    x8, x8, x13
    0x1001de688 <+300>: orr    x10, x8, x12
    0x1001de68c <+304>: str    x10, [sp, #8]
    0x1001de690 <+308>: add    x8, x11, #1               ; =1 
    0x1001de694 <+312>: orr    w11, wzr, #0x8
    0x1001de698 <+316>: umulh  x11, x8, x11
    0x1001de69c <+320>: cmp    xzr, x11
    0x1001de6a0 <+324>: b.ne   0x1001de6e0               ; <+388>
    0x1001de6a4 <+328>: lsl    x11, x8, #3
    0x1001de6a8 <+332>: cmp    x11, #63                  ; =63 
    0x1001de6ac <+336>: b.hi   0x1001de714               ; <+440>
    0x1001de6b0 <+340>: orr    w12, wzr, #0x80
    0x1001de6b4 <+344>: bfxil  x12, x0, #0, #6
    0x1001de6b8 <+348>: and    w9, w9, #0xff
    0x1001de6bc <+352>: lsl    x9, x9, x11
    0x1001de6c0 <+356>: orr    x9, x9, x10
    0x1001de6c4 <+360>: str    x9, [sp, #8]
    0x1001de6c8 <+364>: add    x8, x8, #1                ; =1 
    0x1001de6cc <+368>: mov    x0, x12
    0x1001de6d0 <+372>: orr    w10, wzr, #0x8
    0x1001de6d4 <+376>: umulh  x10, x8, x10
    0x1001de6d8 <+380>: cmp    xzr, x10
    0x1001de6dc <+384>: b.eq   0x1001de6e4               ; <+392>
    0x1001de6e0 <+388>: brk    #0x1
    0x1001de6e4 <+392>: lsl    x10, x8, #3
    0x1001de6e8 <+396>: cmp    x10, #64                  ; =64 
    0x1001de6ec <+400>: b.hs   0x1001de714               ; <+440>
    0x1001de6f0 <+404>: and    x11, x0, #0xff
    0x1001de6f4 <+408>: lsl    x10, x11, x10
    0x1001de6f8 <+412>: orr    x9, x10, x9
    0x1001de6fc <+416>: str    x9, [sp, #8]
    0x1001de700 <+420>: add    x9, sp, #8                ; =8 
    0x1001de704 <+424>: add    x8, x8, x9
    0x1001de708 <+428>: add    x1, x8, #1                ; =1 
    0x1001de70c <+432>: add    x0, sp, #8                ; =8 
    0x1001de710 <+436>: b      0x1001de578               ; <+28>
    0x1001de714 <+440>: adr    x0, #723006               ; "fatal error"
    0x1001de718 <+444>: nop    
    0x1001de71c <+448>: adr    x3, #723412               ; "shift amount is larger than type size in bits"
    0x1001de720 <+452>: nop    
    0x1001de724 <+456>: movz   w1, #0xb
    0x1001de728 <+460>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
    0x1001de72c <+464>: movz   w4, #0x2d
    0x1001de730 <+468>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
    0x1001de734 <+472>: bl     0x1001de55c               ; <+0>
    0x1001de738 <+476>: adr    x0, #722970               ; "fatal error"
    0x1001de73c <+480>: nop    
    0x1001de740 <+484>: adr    x3, #726480               ; "value is outside of Unicode codespace"
    0x1001de744 <+488>: nop    
    0x1001de748 <+492>: movz   w1, #0xb
    0x1001de74c <+496>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
    0x1001de750 <+500>: movz   w4, #0x25
    0x1001de754 <+504>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
    0x1001de758 <+508>: bl     0x1001de55c               ; <+0>
```

This is the code for the view controller that I am accessing with dest:
(Thanks to Emptyless)

```
//
//  SecondViewController.swift
//  FoodTracker
//
//  Created by Michael Buerger on 7/4/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Michael Buerger. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!
    var mealName: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if mealName != nil {
            mealNameLabel.text = mealName
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Check that the label is bound by the storyboard

Comment: Please provide relevant code from your Xcode project.

Comment: Please only ever (now and in the future) paste code and error information as text directly into the question.  Limit use of images for demonstrating UI-related information.  @Emptyless has done you the favor of translating your code from the image provided, but you'll have to do the same for your error message.  Simply click the `edit` link below the question (directly above these comments) to improve your question.  You may have to wait until the pending edit has been approved by the community reviewers to do that.

Comment: I edited the post to include the code as text instead of an image, I will do this in the future, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that you are accessing an IBOutlet that has not yet been initialized. If instead of setting the `UITextLabel` directly you create a variable that holds the text you might have more luck:

As property of SecondViewController:

```
var labelText : String?
```

In `prepareForSegue()` of FirstViewController:

```
des.labelText = "Your Text"
```

and in the `viewDidLoad()` of SeconViewController:

```
self.MeatNameLabel.text = labelText
```

Comment: This works, thanks, I would upvote this but I can't because of my reputation.

Comment: No @MichaelBuerger.  The outlets aren't set until after `prepareForSegue`.  This answer is the correct solution.